# How number value Search in MongoDB Atlas work?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I'm newbie to MongoDB Atlas. I want to execute a query as below,

Sample document:

```
{
  message: "Hello",
  role: "student",
  status: 1
}
```

Query

```
search 
WHERE 
'Hello' in field 'message' 
NOT [1 OR 2] in field 'status'
```

I tried with `compound` and `search` as below, but couldn't get what I want.

```
compound:{
    must:[{
      text: {
        query: 'Hello',
        path: 'message'
      }
    }],
   
    mustNot:[
      {
      text: {
        query: 1,
        path: 'status'
      }
    },
    {
      text: {
        query: 2,
        path: 'status'
      }
    }
    ]
  }
```

This returns an error saying,

```
"Query" must be a string (from "compund.mustNot[2].text").
```

And when I make those as String it doesn't return any values. I understand that I'm using a text search here, but I couldn't find any other alternatives.
Is it not possible to search int values in MongoDB Atlas?

Answer (score 1):

```
db.getCollection("yourCollection").find({"message":"Hello","status":{$nin:[1,2]}});
```

If you want to use `$in`, you can use it below... using '$in'

```
db.getCollection("yourCollection").find({"message":"Hello","status":{$in:[1,2]}});
```

Answer (score 1):

Somethin if you want to try with find

```
db.collection.find({
  $and: [
    {  message: "Hello" },
    {  status: { $nin: [1,2]}
    }
  ]
})
```

**Working [mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QB5PNIUeKp-)**

If you need to use `$search`, you can use array

```
$search: {
    compound:{
        must:[{
          text: {
            query: 'Hello',
            path: 'message'
          }
        }],
       
        mustNot:[
          {
          text: {
            query: [1,2],
            path: 'status'
          }
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the $search one gives below error in Atlas MongoDb
`caused by :: \"query[0]\" must be a string (from \"compound.mustNot[0].text\")'`

Answer (score 0):

- Try this, check if it works

```
compound:{
    must:[{
      text: {
        query: 'Hello',
        path: 'message'
      }
    }],
   
    mustNot:[
      {
      text: {
        query: 1,
        path: 'status'
      }
    },
    {
      text: {
        query: 2,
        path: 'status'
      }
    },
    {
      regex: {
        query: "([1-2]{1})",
        path: "status",
        allowAnalyzedField: true
      }
    } 
    ]
  }
```

[doc](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/tutorial/run-query/)

Answer (score 0):

We've found that in MongoDB Search any search of a number value must use the [equals](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/equals/) operator on a per-field basis. It also takes a single `value` not an array of `value`. Your example would look something like this:

```
const searchAggregation = {
   index: "some-search-index",
   compound: {
      text: {
         query: "Hello",
         path: "message"
      }
      mustNot: [
         {
            equals: {
               value: 1,
               path: "status"
            }
         },
         {
            equals: {
               value: 2,
               path: "status"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
};
```

It has to be done this way because normal text queries don't work with numbers in Mongo Search (Lucene). They use `equals` operators. And `equals` operators only work on set fields, so they can't be done in a single `equals`, but they can be all added to a compound search.

In reality, in our searches, we do a base `text` search, but then also run a `parseInt()` on the `query` input that returns true if the entire `query` is an integer or if the first key in the query is an integer. If it's true, then we dynamically add the `equals` operators on our various fields passing the parsed integer as the query. We also use `should`:

```
const parseIntQuery = parseInt(query);
if(!isNaN(parseIntQuery)) {
   //  Push the integer comparison for Number field "order"
   searchAggregation.compound.should.push({
      equals: {
         value: parseIntQuery,
         path: "order"
      }
   });

   //  Push the integer comparison for Number field "quantity"
   searchAggregation.compound.should.push({
      equals: {
         value: parseIntQuery,
         path: "quantity"
      }
   });

   //  Push the integer comparison for  Number field "age"
   searchAggregation.compound.should.push({
      equals: {
         value: parseIntQuery,
         path: "age"
      }
   });
}
```